# How can i shade foam along a coastline, together with a sea shader?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural, mathematics

I want to make a procedural texture for terrain, with water, sea foam, sand, moss, and rocks.

I have managed to make them all except for the water foam, which i cannot fix along the shoreline.

Basically, the sea line starts at z=0, where i want to put a few meters of foam shader and the rest will be water, but i did not yet find a way to do it.

Can somebody give some suggestions? Thanks.

[image: where foam should be]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're doing something like this to generate the terrain.

[image]

Regardless, with whatever method you've used it should be possible to identify the handle that affects the coastline.

[image]

So in my case I could duplicate this *Color Ramp* and use the current position of that handle to mark the coast, and then create a new mask on the other side of it for a foam shader mix factor.  This does have the unfortunate side-effect of catching a bunch of the terrain.  I don't know if this happens with every method, but regardless we'll fix that next.

[image]

You've said that the water is at Z = 0, and I've made sure mine is the same.  To isolate only the coast, we can take Object Coordinates and separate out the Z axis.  Run this through an inverse operation and *Clamp* the result.

[image]

This has given us a mask for the islands.  The jaggies are down to the level of subdivision.  I was using *Adaptive* so I set my *Dicing Scale* really low to make them go away for this screenshot.

[image]

We can subtract this mask from our *Color Ramp* output, also *Clamping*, and get the coast, at that point we can go back to the *Color Ramp* and adjust the threshold to taste.

[image]

[image]